# Why a integer pointer automatically changed to 0x384

Tags: c, pointers

Phenomenon: Since Fabi is passed through the pointer parameter, the address of Fabi enters the function normally for the first time. The second time Fabi becomes an inaccessible address 0x384(Watcher), but it has not been changed by itself and passed to the function as const.

The fibonacci_search function uses the global variable Fabi instead of the Fabi parameter, so there is no problem.

It is precisely because the inaccessible address is accessed, a Segmentation fault is reported, and the program terminates.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci_search( const int* const F,int* a,int n,int val){
    int low = 0, high=n-1,maxn = n-1;
    int mid;
    int k = 0;
    while(maxn>F[k]-1)
        k++;
    for(int i=maxn;i<F[k]-1;i++)
        a[i]=a[maxn];

    int i=1;
    while(low <= high){
        mid = low + F[k-1] - 1; //mid = low + F[k] - 1;
        printf("The %dth search value is:%d\n",i++,a[mid]);
        if( val < a[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
            k = k-1;
        }else if( val > a[mid]){
            low = mid + 1;
            k = k-2;
        }else{
            if(mid<=n)
                return mid;
            else
                return maxn; 
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


int main(void){
    int biarr[] = {0,1,16,24,35,47,59,62,73,88,99,102,304,758,777,801,900};

    int amount = 15;
    int* Fabi= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*amount);
    Fabi[0]=0;Fabi[1]=1;
    for(int i=2;i<amount;i++){
        Fabi[i]=Fabi[i-1]+Fabi[i-2];
    }

    for(int i =5;i<17;i++){
        int result = fibonacci_search(Fabi,biarr,17,biarr[i]);
        if(result == -1)
            printf("Can not find the result.\n");
        else
            printf("Find the Value,the Index is:%d\n",result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNSWB.jpg)

Comment: When you debug, have you made sure that there's no out-of-bounds writes to any of the arrays?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and then explain what happened when you followed the advice there.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why do you need to use dynamic allocation for `Fabi`?

Comment: **fibonacci_search function uses the global variable Fabi instead of the Fabi parameter** There is no such global variable, and the function does use the `F` parameter.

Comment: Please cut and paste the output text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a (possible) overflow here:

```
for(int i=maxn;i<F[k]-1;i++)
        a[i]=a[maxn];
```

How could you be sure that `F[k]-1` is a valid bound for your array `a`?

Comment: Worse than that; `maxn` is initialised to the index of the last element of the array, then _increments_.  It will either overrun or do nothing, so the code is wrong either way.

Answer (score 0):

OMG.
when change

```
int biarr[] = {0,1,16,24,35,47,59,62,73,88,99,102,304,758,777,801,900};
```

to

```
int biarr[50] = {0,1,16,24,35,47,59,62,73,88,99,102,304,758,777,801,900};
```

Its right.

Thanks to: When you debug, have you made sure that there's no out-of-bounds writes to any of the arrays?  Some programmer dude's remind.

Its really  a peculiar phenomenon！！！

Comment: Why do you find that peculiar?  All these variables are adjacent to eachother in memory, if you overrun one object, you stomp over some other.  You created a 17 element array and then immediately start writing off the end in the `for(int i=maxn;i<F[k]-1;i++)` loop.  Did you intend to increment rather then decrement `i` there because you initialise it to index the _last_ element.  I am willing to bet you corrupted `amount ` also.

Comment: I doubt that your "solution" is the fix you think it is.  You have simply separated the variables with some "buffer space" so your bug becomes latent/benign and stops it from crashing. A smell remains around this code.  Use a debugger and step through watching variables at each step to be sure it is doing what you intended.  If it is doing what you intended, be sure what you intended is valid.  Arrays in C do not magically expand to accommodate added content - they are fixed pre-allocated size.  This is not Python, it is build for speed, not for comfort.